# Spark context Hadoop configuration aws key update

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to update session token in spark session after expire of AWS token with new token information but still sparkcontext is using older information and causing the failure of job (i.e. I am tried to print the session information and it is printing new values only). When I tried to test with same new token with new session then it is able to connect. Can't we update the session token with latest token information in spark context? Please advise.

Comment: Could you add the code, how are you accessing the token, and how are you updating it?

Comment: Here is the piece of logic used to update the AWS Credentials in sparkContext..

def credUpdate(awsKey):String,awsSecret:String,awsToken:String): Boolean ={
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', awsKey)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', awsSecret)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.session.token',awsToken)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
}